# Pass to another page after successfully login using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to go to another page after login so How can I pass to another page after successfully login using Ajax and php ? when ajax send a request to php and then get the response like (if the response is ('true') or ('false') this responses depends on checking the username and password) so i do not know how to deal with this response in ajax to use it as a condition to pass to the next page. please help.

```
   function doCallAjax(Mode) {

      HttPRequest = false;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari,...
         HttPRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
         if (HttPRequest.overrideMimeType) {
            HttPRequest.overrideMimeType('text/html');
         }
      } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
         try {
            HttPRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
         } catch (e) {
            try {
               HttPRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {}
         }
      }

      if (!HttPRequest) {
         alert('Cannot create XMLHTTP instance');
         return false;
      }

      var url = 'PHP_Login.php';


      var pmeters = "tEmail=" + encodeURI( document.getElementById("Email").value) +
                    "&tpassword=" + encodeURI( document.getElementById("password").value ) +

                    "&tMode=" + Mode;



        HttPRequest.open('POST',url,true);


        HttPRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        HttPRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-length", pmeters.length);
        HttPRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        HttPRequest.send(pmeters);


        HttPRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
        {

             if(HttPRequest.readyState == 3)  // Loading Request
              {
               document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML = "Now is Loading...";

              }

             if(HttPRequest.readyState == 4) // Return Request
              {
               document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML = HttPRequest.responseText;
               document.getElementById("Email").value = '';
               document.getElementById("password").value = '';

           }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The way this system usually works is upon authentication in the backend, the php usually creates a session variable whether logged in or not and then sends back a response. Once the response is got, all you have to do is redirect in javascript using `window.location()` or `window.href` functions of javascript.

Comment: i do not know what type of condition i have to write to deal with the response from php to pass to the next page

Comment: `if(HttPRequest.readyState == 4) // Return Request
              {
               document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML = HttPRequest.responseText;` This is where you will have to check. Its usually done by sending back a json response from php

Comment: i know i asking a lot but please how can i make a condition to compare it with 'true' or 'false' responses which is comes from  php and then if it ture go to the next page?

Comment: What does the response text look like? I mean `HttPRequest.responseText`? You can do a string compare or if its a JSON string, you can objectify it using `JSON.parse(theString)` method. For example, if a response is `{"error":"none","login":true}`, you can use `var response = JSON.parse(HttpRequest.responseText); if(response.login== true){ window.location='user_data.php')}`